# react redux nested dispatch not called

Tags: react-native, redux, redux-thunk

i'm using redux with react native and i need to re-use my actions

```
const fetchPosts = () => {

  return (dispatch) => {

    Api.get('/posts')
       .then(response => dispatch({type: FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS, payload: response}))
       .catch(err => dispatch({type: FETCH_POSTS_FAIL, payload: err}))
  }
}
```

i want to always fetch posts after login

```
const login = ({username, password}) => {

  return (dispatch) => {

    Api.post('/auth', {username, password})
       .then(response => dispatch({type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: response})
       .then(() => fetchPosts())
       .catch(err => dispatch({type: LOGIN_FAIL, payload: err}))
  }
}
```

the problem is fetch posts dispatch never happen because.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should `dispatch(fetchPosts())`, and you can directly call it after `dispatch({type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: response}` in the same `then` callback, or keep it in the second `then` callback, they are both ok:

```
const login = ({username, password}) => {

  return (dispatch) => {

    Api.post('/auth', {username, password})
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: response}
        dispatch(fetchPosts())
      })
      .catch(err => dispatch({type: LOGIN_FAIL, payload: err}))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main reason the code is not working is because fetchPosts did not return a promise. Try the following code:

```js
const fetchPosts = (dispatch) => {
    return Api.get('/posts')
       .then(response => dispatch({type: FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS, payload: response}))
       .catch(err => dispatch({type: FETCH_POSTS_FAIL, payload: err}))
}

const login = ({username, password}) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    Api.post('/auth', {username, password})
       .then(response => dispatch({type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: response})
       .then(() => fetchPosts(dispatch))
       .catch(err => dispatch({type: LOGIN_FAIL, payload: err}))
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry i did a mistake for dispatching Login action (i did correct my code)

Comment: and i want to reuse fetchPosts() somewhere else